# Why is my edited video not rendering all as one?

Tags: rendering, video

I have had two different issues for rendering not as a playable whole video.

a) If I pick FFmpeg, The videos are titled WarriorHunters_0000001-61167, WarriorHunters_0010001-61167, WarriorHunters_0020001-61167 and it is three different videos, but for instance WH_002 has a "ghost" 00:00 - 25:00 and only has video there for 25:00 - 37:00.

b) If I pick AVI raw, it is a 430 GB (!!!) file that also launches and only plays the first 15 seconds before stopping.

It is worth noting, a lot of the seams in the FFmpeg version are near where I do long pan-and-zooms with keyframes.

Comment: Why are you using AVI raw? It is an outdated, inefficient and wasteful format. Most likely your computer cannot sustain the data rate needed to play such files. If your goal is just to playback the video files use mp4. It you are going to further manipulate the files use an image sequence and save as EXR.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much of an answer for the malfunction, except that your frame numbers are huge. The blender manual recommends rendering as frames if it is longer than 2,000 frames, but in this case I recommend rendering it in parts.

PS: The question does not have very clear information, and leaves alot of questions for the answerers to ask. What exactly do you mean by ghost? Does the video show 25 minutes of blank, or does the player just skip ahead? What codecs are you using with FFmpeg? There are several available. How do you do the pan and zooms?

That aside, what is your operating system and graphics card?